# suppose that $Ax = b$ has only one solution, Prove the next properties for $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm asking myself why these relations are true for some matrix $A_{m \times n}$:

1. $Ax = b$ has maximum one solution
2. $Nullity(A) = {0}$
3. rank$(A)= n$
4. the columns of $A$ are linearly independent.

For the relation between the second and the third thing I've yet tried to say: if rank$(A) = n$ then the dimension for the columns vector space is $n$, and therefore the columns are linearly independent. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to reformat your question so it is readable. It might also be a good idea to show us what you have tried.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [rank nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) which explains why knowing that there exist one and only solution for the system $Ax =b$, would prove\disprove the four different questions you were suggesting.

As for the relation, Notice that for some matrix $A_{m \times n}$ as $m \neq n$, Let us suppose there exist one and only solution for which $Ax =  b$, then we'd like to prove/ disprove that $Nullity(A) = 0$.

this is true if and only if $b = 0$. the nullity of a matrix is the set of vectors for which $Ax =0$. so if there exist only one, and that is zero, then by a definition we get that section (1) $\longrightarrow$  (2).

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand (2) -> (3), but not yet completely (1) -> (2), I don't really understand why Ax=b has only one sollution iff b=0?

Comment: $(1) \rightarrow (2)$ if and only if $b=0$, which is immidat from the definition of the Nullity of a matrix. which is, the set of all vectors ${x_1, x_2, \ldots}$ that for which $Ax_{i} = 0$. if $Ax =0 \iff x =0$, then dim $Nulll(A) = 0 $. because there exist no $x_{i} \in Null(A) \iff x = 0 \Longrightarrow i = 0$

Comment: I understand what you say, but not how it relates to Ax=B has only one sollution...

Comment: $b$ is zero, otherwise there could be only two options. 1. there's no solution. 
2. there is more than one solution (2 or infinity, that doesn't matter). both cases, $Null(A) > 0$

Comment: why can't there be just one sollution if b !=0?

Comment: because for every matrix, $A \cdot 0 = 0$ then $b = 0$ is a solution...

and then you have two solutions...

Comment: wow and then b is in the kernel?

Comment: thanks now I understand ;)

Comment: yes, the kernel and the nullity are the same

Comment: nullity = kernel of a matrix

Comment: Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Sorry for another question but AX=b should have maximum one sollution so also no sollution can be the case, so then b can be not 0 I guess?